# Kotlin: how to use reduce/fold with a data structure as the accumulative argument?

Tags: kotlin

I want to use reduce/fold methods to create a new list from an existing List. This is the code I tried to write:

```
val list: List<Int> = listOf(1, 2, 3)
val newList = mutableListOf<Int>()
    val sum: List<Int> = list.fold(newList) { (acc: List<Int>, i: Int) -> {
        acc.add(i + 10)
        acc
    }}
```

It doesn't compile.

I want that newList will be (11,12,13).
How can I do it in a functional manner?

In Javascript, for example, this code compiles:

```
list.reduce((acc, item) => {
   acc.push(item + 10)
   return acc;
}, [])
```

Comment: Note that JavaScript also has `map`, so your example could be simplified to `list.map((item) => item+10)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most convenient and functional way to do what you want is using `map` function:

```
val list: List<Int> = listOf(1, 2, 3)
val newList: MutableList<Int> = list.map { it + 10 }.toMutableList()
```

But if you really want to use `fold` for some (strange) reason, you can do it this way:

```
val newList: MutableList<Int> = 
    list.fold(ArrayList()) { acc, x -> acc.apply { add(x + 10) } }
```

Or this way:

```
val newList: MutableList<Int> = 
    list.fold(ArrayList()) { acc, x -> 
        acc += x + 10
        acc
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. And yet, I was looking for a way to do it with reduce/fold. Isn't there any way to do it in Kotlin?

Comment: _"And yet, I was looking for a way to do it with reduce/fold"_ Why? Is this some kind of interview question? `map` makes much more sense for producing the result you want. `reduce`/`fold` is for aggregation, which is a different type of operation.